# How to add a map marker to map? Windows Phone

Tags: c#, windows-phone-8, dictionary, overlay

I have passed a GeoCoordinate variable to the page of my map class, but when I try to draw a marker to the map I get an error stating that `GeoCoordinate is a 'type' but is used as a 'variable'` It also gives me syntax error for the `;` at `PositionOrigin = new Point(0.5, 0.5);`
 and the closing `;`.

I understand from this that my syntax must be incorrect for adding a map marker due to getting this error. My question is how do I correct this method to draw the marker?
 Am I drawing the marker the correct way or is there a different solution?

This is the onNaviagatedTo method of the map page where I pass the coordinates and try to add a marker:

```
protected override void OnNavigatedTo(NavigationEventArgs e)
        {
            if (NavigationContext.QueryString.ContainsKey("GeoLat") && NavigationContext.QueryString.ContainsKey("GeoLong"))
            {
                var latitude = Convert.ToDouble(NavigationContext.QueryString["GeoLat"]);
                var longtitude = Convert.ToDouble(NavigationContext.QueryString["GeoLong"]);
                var MyGeoPosition = new GeoCoordinate(latitude, longtitude);

                var overlay = new MapOverlay
                {
                    PositionOrigin = new Point(0.5, 0.5); //syntax error
                    GeoCoordinate = MyGeoPosition; //error thrown here
                    Content = new TextBlock{Text = "My car"}; 

                    var ml = new MapLayer { overlay }; 
                    MyMap.Layers.Add(ml);
                }; //syntax error

            }
```

Comment: I found the answer to your question about the center layout, but you have already been deleted. Found the answer? :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Looks to me like you're missing an equal sign.

```
MapOverlay overlay = new MapOverlay()
{
    PositionOrigin = new Point(0.5, 0.5),
    GeoCoordinate = MyGeoPosition,
    Content = new TextBlock{Text = "My car"},
};
MapLayer ml = new MapLayer { overlay };
MyMap.Layers.Add(ml);
```

Or, you could just do this with PushPins:

```
PushPin myPin = new Pushpin();
myPin.Location = MyGeoPosition;
myPin.Content = "My car";
MyMap.Children.Add(myPin);
```

Comment: Tried the above,gives me `GeoCoordinate is a type but is used like a variable` Also gives me syntax errors at semicolon on first line and closing bracket.Any ideas?

Comment: Sorry, I was just copying what you had above & adding the equal sign - fixed the syntax.

Comment: I tried the above but for some reason when I run the app, the map just shows up uncentered with no map marker..Have I missed something along the way that its missing adding the marker?

Comment: Are you calling MyMap.SetView to center the map on MyGeoPosition? The overlay adds something to the map but so far as I'm aware it doesn't actually alter your map.

Comment: So I could use the pushpin code instead of the map overlay code?